# How do I get a column value from multiple sheets

Tags: java, api, google-docs, google-forms

I have a working script to create a Google Doc from a Google Form, but I want to change one of my values to sheet2.  I am using sheet2 to =CLEAN a column due to line breaks I can't get rid of in column 3 on sheet1.  I replicated my script for a simple form/doc below to test. I want var title to pull values from column 5 on sheet 2 instead of column 3 on sheet 1.  Or perhaps there is a better way to solve my formatting issues of line breaks remaining in my created Doc from template?

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
   
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var firstName = e.values[1];
  var lastName = e.values[2];
  var title = e.values[3];
          
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("17HH3zii-MfT3vl7-JU9Xx8XNgWpPAcNG5244iJHnzo0");
  var templateSubmittedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1QNaCCyueyLvcuB7w8wkYvjt-OW75scPP");
  
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName + ',' + firstName, templateSubmittedFolder);
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}", firstName);
  body.replaceText("{{LastName}}", lastName);
  body.replaceText("{{Title}}", title);
  
  var currentDate = new Date();   

  doc.saveAndClose();
  
}
```

Comment: Could you share the example spreadsheet response page?  My guess is you could handle the changes needed in your script rather than cleaning it in the spreadsheet then collecting from there.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sixodNLz5YAFNF9iVnPlS74W2omEm29h9u15CZci-Qg/edit#gid=1919166902 .   Thank you

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  Mind making the link access available to public?

Comment: I created it on my work network and so I will need to recreate this on my personal account or grant permission if that works?

Comment: made a copy which has a public link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16hhml5HEGNogMX9AbFHmwl7WtRIhBwE3PLx93QBPCvc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've provided, one small change is needed. Instead of

```
var title = e.values[3];
```

Just add in a replace to remove all nonprintable text like so

```
var title = e.values[3].replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '');
```

Below is the full code with the edit.  Good luck!

```
    function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
   
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var firstName = e.values[1];
  var lastName = e.values[2];
  var title = e.values[3].replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '');
          
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("17HH3zii-MfT3vl7-JU9Xx8XNgWpPAcNG5244iJHnzo0");
  var templateSubmittedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1QNaCCyueyLvcuB7w8wkYvjt-OW75scPP");
  
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName + ',' + firstName, templateSubmittedFolder);
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}", firstName);
  body.replaceText("{{LastName}}", lastName);
  body.replaceText("{{Title}}", title);
  
  var currentDate = new Date();   

  doc.saveAndClose();
  
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough.  I also added this to my actual Form to Doc script as well as this short test version and it works.  I added a space in the quotes so the line break turned into one space instead of no spaces.  Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome!  If it answered your question, go ahead and mark it as an answer.  Have a great day!